# Unable to shutdown or reboot ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, shutdown, reboot

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my laptop. After installation my system was unable to restart and was stuck at black-blank screen. After no response i manually turn off my machine then when i booted up system it worked fine. Later when i tried to shutdown, it again got stuck at black screen then i had to again turn off my machine manually. I also do not have a dedicated graphic card on my system. It runs Intel HD graphics. Please provide me some solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the brug config. I noticed that after shutdown my system was stuck after the line "target shutdown reached", so i replaced "quit splash"  with "noapic" . Now it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Boot your system then try to shut it down again.
When it goes black-blank screen, try hitting the F4 key.
This should display system messages and allow you to see if there's some error message. For instance, it could be a service waiting forever for termination.

If hitting F4 doesn't work, reboot again. Then, when you're on logging screen, hit the Ctrl+Alt+F1 key combination. This will display your first TTY.
Log in with your usual username (you will need sudo permissions), then try shutting down your system whith the following command :

> poweroff

Again, this shoud display system messages and allow you to see if there are any errors. If it goes black-blank again, then, at next reboot, you might have a look at your `/var/log/syslog` file to determine what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried these methods but it does not seems to be working.

Comment: Now i am getting black screen with blinking underscore (_) cursor after shutting down the system. And the screen is stuck there.

Comment: That's quite weird. Can you at least log in to TTY1 with the Ctrl+Alt+F1 key combination after rebooting ?

Comment: I tried to change the brug config. and replaced "quit splash" with "acpi= off" now it seems to be working. For now atleast.

Comment: Okay. So, problem solved. :-)

Comment: Yes , by changing brig config. to "acpi=off" it only worked for some time , then I again changed brug by replacing acpi=off with "noapic", now its properly shutting down. So problem solved. Thanks for your response. 